# Order legend in same order that the (last value of) the plots are displayed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am adding plots to a figure within a loop, so when I add a legend to the figure, it is ordered in the same order that the plots were added. Instead I would like to order the legend, intuitively, as the plots are displayed in the figure. Some of the plots overlap and cross over each other in some cases, so when I say "as the plots are displayed in the figure", a more definitive definition would be to order the legends based on the last y-value of each plot.

Here is my code as of now:

```
heights = [3, 4]

algos = ["NegaMax w/o PV",
         "PVS w/o PV",
         "NegaMax w/ PV",
         "PVS w/ PV"]

# (H, B, Algo, Approx)
temp = np.swapaxes(results, 2, 3)

for i in range(temp.shape[0]):
    for j in range(temp.shape[2]):
        plt.plot(temp[i][-1][j], label="{} (H = {})".format(algos[j], heights[i]))

plt.title("Num of Evaluations for each Algorithm at each Height with Maximum Branching Factor")
plt.xlabel("\'Aprox\' Value")
plt.ylabel("Number of Evaluations")
plt.xticks(np.arange(7), np.arange(0, 301, 50))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which displays this figure:

[image]

[Here is my`results` numpy array.](https://pastebin.com/cpKXJaL5)

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to obtain the order of the elements from the last data row, e.g. using `numpy.argsort`, order the handles and labels accordingly and supply the ordered handles and labels to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.,3.4)
phis = np.linspace(0.3,6.2,5)
y = np.array([np.sin(x+phi) for phi in phis]).T

labels = ["sin({:.2f}*x)".format(phi) for phi in phis]

plt.plot(x,y, label="unknown")

order = np.argsort(y[-1,:])[::-1]
h, l = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles=list(np.array(h)[order]),labels=list(np.array(labels)[order]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Quastiat That is not part of the code shown here. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317 for methods to get the legend outside.